# Application starts with 86% memory usage(HeapSize)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, heap-memory, android-support-library, heap-size

I'm developing application for Android(Xamarin). At current moment is like prototype(inside nothing heavy).
I added app7compat support library and also implemented toolbar with navigation Drawer Layout.
I make some test on real device(Samsung Galaxy ***S4 Active***) and it's an like glitch/bug,because when application started,android device monitor showing this :
[image]

How that is possible? My activity contains:

1. Toolbar(with Drawer layout)
2. Some different  controls,like **imageView** and **imageButtons**

As i said,that comes from start(i mean that this 86% used memory allocated with strange items,because there is no computing logic).
Why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guys explained for me,that is ok,because from start application eats 86% of ***allocated*** memory(after that if needed, will grow up).

Anothers tip was,to put flag **largeHeap** and via **RunTime()**,to see how much memory can be allocated:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory/1024/1024));
```

and my result(**Samsung Galaxy S4 Active**) was :

> 512MB

Hope that helps!